# For saving a single large object in R, is saveRDS or save faster?

Tags: r

I currently have a very large array (500 elements, each with a 1000 by 20 matrix). I have been using `saveRDS` to save objects. However, it consistently takes a very long time to do so. I am wondering if `save()` is faster, or if there are options in each to save things faster? Thanks.

Comment: list of matrix objects or an N-rank array?

Comment: Hi, my apologies but it appears that it is a list of not only matrix objects but regression fit outputs. My list is called `My.List`, and it contains 500 list objects. So if I call `My.List[[1]]', it outputs a matrix of 1000 by 20 and also a regression fit output.

Comment: Check this out for a faster alternative to saveRDS: https://github.com/traversc/qs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always spelunk a bit in the sources:

#### `saveRDS()`:

```
function (object, file = "", ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, compress = TRUE, 
    refhook = NULL) {}
...
  .Internal(serializeToConn(object, con, ascii, version, refhook))
}
```

Eventually: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2c3e0e757e81ca23c34da8dde4ff925bd9d275f0/src/main/serialize.c#L2471-L2536

#### `save()`:

```
function (..., list = character(), file = stop("'file' must be specified"), 
    ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, envir = parent.frame(), compress = isTRUE(!ascii), 
    compression_level, eval.promises = TRUE, precheck = TRUE) {
...
  .Internal(saveToConn(list, con, ascii, version, envir,  eval.promises))
}
```

Eventually: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6ac8f58c608337200f85ea47cba2abc717be6eb5/src/main/saveload.c#L1973-L2041

OR

give it a benchmark (List assuming it's a list of matrix objects):

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(0)

lapply(1:500, function(i) {
  matrix(sample(20*1000), nrow = 1000, ncol = 20)
}) -> matrix_list

print(str(matrix_list, list.len=5))
## List of 500
##  $ : int [1:1000, 1:20] 17934 5310 7442 11456 18161 4033 17963 18887 13211 12577 ...
##  $ : int [1:1000, 1:20] 2227 4212 2296 2907 6198 3005 10531 2358 9543 15374 ...
##  $ : int [1:1000, 1:20] 5969 11861 11057 11933 7852 17959 14794 530 16811 17003 ...
##  $ : int [1:1000, 1:20] 1073 14634 12948 16282 2087 6687 7992 7640 18482 8043 ...
##  $ : int [1:1000, 1:20] 10900 8249 6059 10767 15541 17139 11663 9010 576 14900 ...
##   [list output truncated]
## NULL

pryr::object_size(matrix_list)
## 40.1 MB

microbenchmark(
  save = save(matrix_list, file = "/tmp/out.rda"),
  saveRDS = saveRDS(matrix_list, file = "/tmp/out.rds"),
  times = 5,
  control = list(warmup = 2)
) -> mb

mb
## Unit: seconds
##     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
##     save 8.571138 8.578461 8.747248 8.650629 8.665557  9.270453     5
##  saveRDS 8.647355 8.655231 9.298947 8.684998 8.772102 11.735052     5
```

You can play with the `compress` & `compression_level` settings in `save()` and `level` in `gzcon()` for use in `saveRDS()` with `compress` to see if changing or removing compression helps.

Comment: I would expect lower compression level or no compression to be fastest. The hardware would determine the magnitude.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That really depends (1) on your hardware performance (CPU vs storage latency), (2) the quality of the compression implementation, (3) the compressibility of the data. For moderately easily compressible data, high compression *should* provide faster reading and writing, even on a relatively fast storage medium (that said, I know that the reality is somewhat different … that’s partly a quality of implementation issue).

Answer (score 0):

The qs package provides a faster alternative for saving and loading R objects. You can use the qs::qsave() function to save your Seurat object more efficiently.

Here’s how you can use it:

```
# Install the qs package if you haven't already
install.packages("qs")

# Save your Seurat object using qsave
qs::qsave(your_seurat_object, file = "path/to/your/seurat_object.qs")
```